# Problem while installing httpd-2.2.4

Tags: httpd

I am trying to in stall httpd-2.2.4 on  the linux VM.
Steps I followed are as follows:
1. Downloaded file: httpd-2.2.4.tar.bz2
2. tar –xvf   httpd-2.2.4.tar.bz2
3. cd  httpd-2.2.4
4. ./configure

after this when I am trying to compile it using "make" command it is giving me following error:

libtool: link: only absolute run-paths are allowed
make[2]: *** [htpasswd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/httpd-2.2.4/support'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/root/httpd-2.2.4/support'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

How to resolve this problem. I have all the devel packages installed on my machine.

Comment: Did you pass any specific parameters to ./configure?

Comment: yeah i tried with different options it didn't work with any of them.
Like:

$ ./configure

$ CC="pgcc" CFLAGS="-O2" \
./configure --prefix=/sw/pkg/apache \
--enable-rewrite=shared \
--enable-speling=shared

and few more .....

Answer (score 1):

seems like a rpath problem... libtool wants the complete path, did you try:

./configure --libdir=/usr/lib/

Try the above config option with whatever your lib path is and post back.. And please post the complete output, i think you may be leaving something out..